# How can you change all past posts' images to link to none instead of the image file?

Tags: posts, media

I'm working with a new client who has a ton of existing posts. She has a lot of inline images and for some reason they all link to the image files. I know how to change this for future posts by adding this to the functions.php file:

```
update_option('image_default_link_type','none');
```

But how would I bulk change the link for all images in all past posts? It would literally take ages to go through and manually change them all.